# Using conditional imports as a way to utilize different functions with the same namespace

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, import, module

I am a beginner python programmer, and I am working on a selenium project in python 2.7.

I have a generic scraper script, that basically outlines what I want to do with all the websites that I visit.  However, because of the nature of the data that I want to grab, I can't run the same code on each site-- each site needs to run it's own individual code.

I have attempted to solve this by importing inside of an if statement, and this is the solution I came up with:

```
site = False
if source_website == "Website A":
    from website_a import *
    site = True
elif source_website == "Website B":
    from website_b import *
    site = True
else:
    print "This is not an acceptable website!"

if site == True:
    # main code block
    driver = driver_setup(chrome)
    driver.get(source_website_URL)
    stuff_to_save = do_some_stuff(driver)
    xml_file(stuff_to_save)
    driver.quit()
```

where the `website_a` and `website_b` modules both have functions named `do_some_stuff`, and they do stuff specific to the website that they're on.  Now, this seems to work, for the most part. I also seem to be able to extend functionality to any number of websites, given that I program a module called `website_c` with the function `do_some_stuff`, and add that to the conditional import.

So, my question is, is this a good idea? Is there a better way to do something like this?

I have literally never seen anyone wrap import statements inside of if statements like this-- and generally, if no one seems to do it, there's usually a good reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `from somewhere import *` is not a good idea due to namespace pollution. If you want the website-specific code in separate modules, why not do something like

```
import importlib

website_modules = {'Website A': 'website_a', 'Website B': 'website_b'}

# ...

website = importlib.import_module(website_modules[source_website])

# use with website.function_name
```

Comment: This is quite useful.  However, doesn't doing things this way create overhead by requiring all modules to be imported at the beginning?  What happens as the number of websites that I give the program the capability to parse increases?  And, since I wrote the modules `from somewhere import *`, it guarantees me control over the namespace (every function imported is used).

Comment: I'll edit my question to import the modules lazily. I don't understand the second part of the comment, as the `*` syntax does not give the importing module control—anything in the imported module will go into the global namespace.

Comment: I mean, I wrote the modules `website_a` and `website_b`, they have exactly the same functions in them, and every function in each module is referenced in the main script (they are functionally different versions of each other, appropriate to the given website).  I (think) I understand the bit about it all going into the global namespace, but I don't see what's actually wrong with that, since this is a script based project that exits outright upon completion.

Comment: You are trying to use modules like classes.  Just make classes.

Comment: @kreativitea I get what you are saying, and in this case, it might be fine. The problem for someone reading your code (including you in a few weeks or months) is trying to find out where a function is defined. For example, I see `do_some_stuff(driver)` in your code. I can find where `driver` is defined by searching in the current file, but if `do_some_stuff` comes with `from website_a import *` a single-file search won't find it.

Comment: @sr2222 Classes it is, then.  I'm still at the point where I'm not entirely comfortable with classes (I don't really understand the details of how they change the namespace), but I'll give it a shot if this is what they're meant to be used for.  Thanks.

Comment: imo, worrying about namespace pollution is a much more advanced concept than classes, you should probably learn it first.  :)  In any case, classes help to keep your module namespace cleaner, because their members are all class and instance scope rather than module scope (unless you explicitly alias them in module scope... but that's another question).

Comment: update:

Thanks again for the suggestion, gentlemen(or ladies).  I managed to apply classes in this situation and it worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

Explore the page object model pattern (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects).  You should model each page as a unique entity, then have some logic that determines what page type you are displaying (either explicitly by having you specify it or implicitly by inspecting the URL and the contents of the page) and then expose the methods to capture the data you need on those objects rather than working directly with the webdriver instance.  You should ultimately aim for something like:

```
for page_identifier in ['page1', 'page2', 'page3']:
    page = navigate_to(page_identifier)
    extracted_data = page.get_data()
    xml_file.write(extracted_data)
```

Comment: Ah, in the actual code, I do this, I just left it out for clarity in the post.  Thank you, though.  The page types all have the same function, so the logic that I use to deal with each page is identical-- I don't have to instruct the program to do different things-- just that the tags that are used to get things from each individual page is particular to each page.

Comment: Yup, which is one of the main reasons to use object oriented design.  You get a page object back from `navigate_to`, all page objects have `get_data`, so you just call the same method on each page object.  `navigate_to` is the only method that has to know the difference between the objects, the caller just cares that the returned pages have `get_data`.  You import all the page objects in to the module with `navigate_to`, then have conditional logic there to create the correct object at runtime.  No conditional imports.

Comment: I have it set up so that the user provides the website that they want to scrape, and depending on the user import, a different module is loaded.  in each respective module, i have a function called `go_search` which has the code that runs a search using whatever search API that particular website uses (or in some cases, simply finds the search box and sends keys, whichever is faster).  In either case, the result of the `go_search` function is the same, but because I'm dealing with completely different websites, trying to abstract a layer that works with any website is near impossible (for me).